# Spring Activiti: Getting list of current tasks - java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, activiti

I've got a activiti diagram that I'm working on. At one point, it goes through a service task, which is supposed to display all the current, or active task IDs and names.

Here's my code:

```
import org.activiti.engine.ProcessEngine;
import org.activiti.engine.TaskService;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.DelegateExecution;
import org.activiti.engine.delegate.JavaDelegate;
import org.activiti.engine.task.Task;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class KillTaskGeneric implements JavaDelegate{
    @Autowired
    private ProcessEngine processEngine;
    @Override
    public void execute(DelegateExecution execution) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Retrieving task list.");
        String processInstanceId = execution.getProcessInstanceId();
        TaskService tskSvc = execution.getEngineServices().getTaskService();

        List<Task> instanceTaskList = tskSvc.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).list();
        for (Task taskItem: instanceTaskList){
            System.out.println(taskItem.getId() + " " + taskItem.getName());
        }
    }

}
```

And here's the service task xml:

```
<serviceTask id="svcKillTask" name="Kill Other Task" activiti:class="com.seerlabs.sonic.api.txn.svctasks.request.KillTaskGeneric"></serviceTask>
```

But every time the process comes to that point, it just stops with the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.seerlabs.sonic.api.txn.svctasks.request.KillTaskGeneric.execute(KillTaskGeneric.java:21)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.JavaDelegateInvocation.invoke(JavaDelegateInvocation.java:34)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DelegateInvocation.proceed(DelegateInvocation.java:37)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.delegate.DefaultDelegateInterceptor.handleInvocation(DefaultDelegateInterceptor.java:25)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.execute(ServiceTaskJavaDelegateActivityBehavior.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.helper.ClassDelegate.execute(ClassDelegate.java:143)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:80)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:116)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:452)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:430)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.leave(ExclusiveGatewayActivityBehavior.java:83)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.execute(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:36)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationActivityExecute.execute(AtomicOperationActivityExecute.java:60)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerStart.java:52)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionCreateScope.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerTake.java:80)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.execute(AtomicOperationTransitionDestroyScope.java:116)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.eventNotificationsCompleted(AtomicOperationTransitionNotifyListenerEnd.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:56)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.pvm.runtime.AbstractEventAtomicOperation.execute(AbstractEventAtomicOperation.java:49)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContext.performOperation(CommandContext.java:96)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperationSync(ExecutionEntity.java:633)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.performOperation(ExecutionEntity.java:628)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:452)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.take(ExecutionEntity.java:430)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:140)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.BpmnActivityBehavior.performDefaultOutgoingBehavior(BpmnActivityBehavior.java:66)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.FlowNodeActivityBehavior.leave(FlowNodeActivityBehavior.java:44)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.leave(AbstractBpmnActivityBehavior.java:47)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.bpmn.behavior.UserTaskActivityBehavior.signal(UserTaskActivityBehavior.java:165)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntity.signal(ExecutionEntity.java:409)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.persistence.entity.TaskEntity.complete(TaskEntity.java:201)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:52)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.CompleteTaskCmd.execute(CompleteTaskCmd.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cmd.NeedsActiveTaskCmd.execute(NeedsActiveTaskCmd.java:59)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandInvoker.execute(CommandInvoker.java:24)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.CommandContextInterceptor.execute(CommandContextInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor$1.doInTransaction(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at org.activiti.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:31)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:35)
    at org.activiti.engine.impl.TaskServiceImpl.complete(TaskServiceImpl.java:175)
    at com.seerlabs.sonic.api.txn.controllers.TxnTaskController.post(TxnTaskController.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1484)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Now I'm a complete noob at this, so I'm not sure what's happening.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which one is line 21 in the source file?

Comment: @dunni That would be the `List<Task> instanceTaskList = tskSvc.createTaskQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).list();`

Comment: Probably too late but i would try to investigate what part of that line is null. is it `tskSvc`, `tskSvc.createTaskQuery().` or `...processInstanceId(processInstanceId)`?